# How to download a java applet class file in a page with an adress like 46.XXX.XX.XX:8008/

Tags: java, applet, ctf

I am working on CTF challenge and there is a link with the challenge, that looks like that : 46.XXX.XX.XX:8008/
If I open the Developer Tools in that page, I can find an applet, with the attribute code with value of "mPage.class"

```html
<applet width="700" height="230" codebase="out" code="mPage.class">
    <param name="_cx" value="13229">
    <param name="_cy" value="6085">
</applet>
```

Usually I would change the url and add mPage.class at the end
For example, if the URL was :
https://website.com/file.shtml
I would type in the url bar:
https://website.com/mPage.class
And I could download the mPage.class file
But since the url doesn't finish with "file.html" or something likes that.
I can't do 46.XXX.XX.XX:8008/mPage.class

When I try to go to http://46.XXX.XX.XX:8008/mPage.class, my browser tell me that the Web page was not found.
I don't know if I can actually download the class file.
Because to get it, I should do something like : 
http://46.XXX.XX.XX:8008/../mPage.class
But it obviously doesn't work. Since I can use the applet in the page, I should Theorically download it.
 
If you find some mistakes, (like spelling one), don't hesitate to warn me, sorry English is not my native language. And thank you for reading.

Comment: I discovered that the url : http://46.XXX.XX.XX:8008/
is the same as the url : http://46.XXX.XX.XX:8008/index.html
<br>Unlike every other example that I've seen, it seems that you can't download the class file, even though you can use the applet in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<applet width="700" height="230" codebase="out" code="mPage.class">
    <param name="_cx" value="13229">
    <param name="_cy" value="6085">
</applet>
```

The important part of finding the class files is to account for the `codebase` specified in the applet element, which effectively means that we need to look in the `out` directory (added to the path of the document) in order to find where the class files actually exist.

So this:

```
http://46.xxx.xx.xx:8008/mPage.class
```

Needs to be this:

```
http://46.xxx.xx.xx:8008/out/mPage.class
```

Comment: I love you, thank you very much. You saved me so much time, I am sincerely grateful.
Edit: Yes, that helped me solve the CTF, thank you very much.